# Remove non numeric characters in a filename except in the extension in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a `file` into a `String` and after that i will replace the name of the converted file without non numeric characters but when i replace it the file extension of the file is also replaced. for example (`2014.05-06.txt` `->` `20140506.txt` but whats happening is `20140506txt`) i want to remain the .txt, .log or any type of extension.

`String strDatefiles = Arrays.toString(saDateFiles).replaceAll("[\\W]", "");`

**Edited:**

```
String[] saDateFiles = fileList.list();
String strDatefiles = Arrays.toString(saDateFiles.substring(0, saDateFiles.lastIndexOf("."))).replaceAll("[\\W]", "");
```

this `saDateFiles.lastIndexOf(".")))` have error replace with a length?

**Edited2:**

```
String[] saDateFiles = fileList.list();
String strDatefiles = Arrays.toString(saDateFiles).substring(0, Arrays.toString(saDateFiles).lastIndexOf(".")).replaceAll("[\\W]","");
System.out.println(strDatefiles);`
```

Output:  `20140502txt20140904` (I have 2 files inside)

Comment: Option #1) split off the extension first, run your regex, tack on the extension again. Option #2) Fix your regex. Option #3) If regex is over your head (that's true for me), just resort to a different approach for the replacing (loop?)

Comment: @domdom I'm new on java btw, can you explain more on how the flow is?

Comment: Looks like other people got you covered already. :)

Comment: @domdom and yeah thanks for what you said its help me little bit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the indexOf the last `.` in the `String`, and then manipulate the two substrings. For example,

```
String saDateFiles = "2014.05-06.txt";
int lastDot = saDateFiles.lastIndexOf('.');
String strDatefiles = saDateFiles.substring(0, lastDot).replaceAll("\\D", "")
        .concat(saDateFiles.substring(lastDot));
System.out.println(strDatefiles);
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
20140506.txt
```

As you noticed, the above was for one file name. To do it for an array of file names, you could use a `for-each` loop and the above code like

```
String[] saDateFilesArr = fileList.list();
for (String saDateFiles : saDateFilesArr) {
    int lastDot = saDateFiles.lastIndexOf('.');
    String strDatefiles = saDateFiles.substring(0, lastDot)
            .replaceAll("\\D", "").concat(saDateFiles.substring(lastDot));
    System.out.println(strDatefiles);
}
```

Comment: I tried your work sir but im having an error could you check my edited post if it's okay?

Comment: but if there is more than 1 file is this will replace the others? I tried it and `2014050220140904.log` this is the result the `20140502` is another file

Answer (score 0):

Apply your replace function to the part of file name before the ".". You can extract this part with the code :

```
fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")) ;
```

Use :

```
String strDatefiles = Arrays.toString(saDateFiles.substring(0, saDateFiles.lastIndexOf("."))).replaceAll("[\\W]", "");
```

Comment: i'm having some problem here `saDateFiles.lastIndexOf(".")))` have error and need to change in `length`? i've edited my question

Comment: look at my edited post i posted the error @DJAM Silvère Gatien

Comment: Sorry, try this : String strDatefiles = Arrays.toString(saDateFiles).substring(0, Arrays.toString(saDateFiles).lastIndexOf(".")).replaceAll("[\\W]", "");

Comment: I tried it and its working but the problem is `20140506txt` this is the result.

Comment: Can you print your code ? You need to add the "." yourself.

Comment: it should be `20140506.txt` and if there is more than 1 file should be `20140506.txt`, `20140507.txt` and so on....

Comment: Can your add the "." yourself ? Like this : String strDatefiles = Arrays.toString(saDateFiles.substring(0, saDateFiles.lastIndexOf("."))).replaceAll("[\\W]", "")+".";

Comment: `String strDatefiles = Arrays.toString(saDateFiles).substring(0, Arrays.toString(saDateFiles).lastIndexOf(".")).replaceAll("[\\W]","").".";` like this? if that its not working....

Comment: Sorry : String strDatefiles = Arrays.toString(saDateFiles).substring(0, Arrays.toString(saDateFiles).lastIndexOf(".")).replaceAll("[‌​\\W]","")+".";